# Django 404: "No object instance found matching the query"

Tags: python, django, view, http-status-code-404

Despite the url arguments being accurate (as far as I can see), Django raises a 404 error when trying to access a specific detail view.

I'm trying to create a detail view for specific car instances in my project. I've just created a slug that passes each car's unique UUID into the url, but Django raises a 404 Error.

It can't find the specific instance, but the urls are accurate and the url accurately matches the id. Also, I'm clicking in from the ListView which works fine.

[image: Corrected error screenshot]
Error screenshot in browser

[image: id confirmation from admin page]
ID confirmation from object admin page. Note that it matches the above url.

**models.py**

```
class CarInstance(models.Model):
    ....
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
    help_text="Unique ID for this car")
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.manufacturer} {self.car_model}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('showroom:car-detail', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('car/<slug:car_detail>/', views.CarDetailView.as_view(), name='car-detail')
]
```

**views.py**

```
class CarDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = CarInstance
    template_name = 'car_detail'
    slug_field = 'car_model'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'car_detail'

    def get_queryset(self):
         return CarInstance.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `slug_field` is not `car_model`, but rather `id`. You are trying to use the wrong thing to find the model.

I got your code to run by changing it to this. The normal caveats about having to make some assumptions apply, so please ask any questions you need to.

```
class CarDetailView(DetailView):
    model = CarInstance
    template_name = 'car_detail'
    slug_field = 'id'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'car_detail'

    def get_queryset(self):
         return CarInstance.objects.all()
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much buddy. It broke the "template_name = 'car_detail'", however, but I changed that to carinstance_detail (to match the generic name) and it works now. Thanks again

Comment: But you might also want to change the url pattern to <uuid:car_detail> as well, just to better match the type of parameter you're expecting in the url. It won't change the behaviour much (because uuid is a subset of slug), but it makes it easier to understand what URL is expected.

Answer (score 3):

You've defined your URL to take a slug, `car_detail`, and then told your view to use the value in that slug to look up in the `car_model` field. But then the URL you go to contains a UUID which you want to look up in the `id` field. Can you not see the disconnect?

If you want to look up by the ID field (ie the primary key), then do so:

```
path('car/<uuid:pk>/', views.CarDetailView.as_view(), name='car-detail')
```

and remove the `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` from the view.

Comment: That was exactly what I originally did. But it raised an AttributeError stating "Generic detail view CarDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf."